# Poker Game Swapping Out Cards For Different Cards

Tags: python

Okay so, I'm onto the next step after dealing the cards to two players.

I need the program to be able to take the player's desired cards it wants to get rid of and exchange them for new random cards. The player will be questioned how many and which cards it wants to exchange. The code should be something like if the player inputs '1' for one throwaway card and then the player has the option to select which card to remove. So that card will then be removed from the hand or list in the code and replaced with 1 new one. This only happens once and then it should print both players' hands.

Every where I look, it's done in a more complicated way and I know it's simple coding but I really do suck at the most simplest things.

What I've got so far:

`def poker():`

`import random`

```
(raw_input('Welcome to a classic game of Poker! You will recieve 5 cards. You will have the option to exchange 1 to 3 cards from your hand for new cards of the same amount you exchanged. IF you have an Ace in your beginning hand, you may exchange that Ace for up to four new cards (three other cards including the ace). ~Press Enter~')) 
(raw_input('S = Spades ,  H = Hearts ,  C = Clubs ,  D = Diamonds ~Press Enter~'))
deck = ['2S','2H','2C','2D','3S','3H','3C','3D','4S','4H','4C','4D','5S','5H','5C','5D','6S','6H','6C','6D','7S','7H','7C','7D','8S','8H','8C','8D','9S','9H','9C','9D','10S','10H','10C','10D','Jack(S)','Jack(H)','Jack(C)','Jack(D)','Queen(S)','Queen(H)','Queen(C)','Queen(D)','King(S)','King(H)','King(C)','King(D)', 'Ace(S)','Ace(H)','Ace(C)','Ace(D)']
new_cards = ''
player1 = []
player2 = []
random.shuffle(deck)

for i in range(5): player1.append(deck.pop(0)) and player2.append(deck.pop(0))

print player1

int(input('How many cards would you like to exchange? 1, 2, 3, or 4 IF you have an Ace.'))


#ignore this for now
int(input('Which card would you like to exchange? 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5? Note: The first card in your hand (or list in this case) is the number 1 spot. So if you want to exchange the first card, input 1. The same is for the other cards.'))
```

The card that was exchanged in the beginning hand also can't be accessible from the deck list after swapping. So like... ['8D','2S','Queen(H),'8S','Jack(H)']
If I wanted to remove 1 card, I choose to remove '2S', '2S' will no longer be in my hand and will be swapped out with a different card from the deck. '2S' will also not return to my hand for any reason because it can't be taken from the list a second time. So the output should be all the same cards EXCEPT the '2S' will be missing and a new card will be in it's place.

There is the standard removing up to 3 cards at once but you can also remove up to 4 cards IF you have an Ace in your beginning hand. But you should be rejected and then asked once more how many cards you want to get rid of if you don't provide an Ace to the question.

Answer (score 0):

What could work is the following :

```
n_cards_to_exchange = int(input('How many cards would you like to exchange? 1, 2, 3, or 4 IF you have an Ace.'))

for i in range(n_cards_to_exchange):
    print(player1)
    card_text = ', '.join([str(j) for j in range(1,5-i)]) + f', or {5-i}?' 
    card_id = int(input(f'Which card would you like to exchange? {card_text} Note: The first card in your hand (or list in this case) is the number 1 spot. So if you want to exchange the first card, input 1. The same is for the other cards.')) - 1
    deck.append(player1.pop(card_id))
random.shuffle(deck)
for i in range(n_cards_to_exchange):
    player1.append(deck.pop(0))
```

The idea is that the player chooses the number of cards he wants to drop, and then chooses which cards he want to drop multiple times. Then he draws back cards from the deck. If you need any clarification, feel free to ask.

Comment: Invalid syntax..? `for i in range(n_cards_to_exchange):`

Comment: Actually, the whole thing isn't working. I tried fixing it, nothing worked.

Comment: I edited the post to fix the syntax error. I checked it, it should work now :)

Comment: Invalid syntax for the card_text variable as well. I hate to bother but maybe my game just hates me. I honestly don't even know what the f in there is used for. I'm that bad at programming.

Comment: Help..? You sure you checked it?

Comment: Just checked again for you, but yes, it worked, I copy pasted the beginning of your code from `deck = ...` to `print player1`, added parenthesis in the `print(player1)`, and it worked. Could you tell me which error you're experiencing?

Comment: Here, check it out first hand, it'll be easier: https://pasteboard.co/HZVlV19.png The invalid syntax error shows up for line 22 and if I find a way to make it go away, it shows up for lines 23-24.

Comment: Which version of python are you using? The error might comes from the syntax `f'...'` which was introduced in python 3.5 if I recall correctly. Just delete this part and check again.

Comment: Ohhh, that would be the problem. I'm using python 2. I did delete the f's but my output isn't what I wanted. Now that I think about, I should've requested a certain output when I first asked the question. I need to have this done by Friday.. I'm toast. Well, either way, thanks a lot for the help and putting up with my persistence.